# Working with Instances from Mesh-Line with Geometry-Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

From a cube I make a simply animation drawing void rectangles.
I would like that every rectangle to be bigger than the previous one. How can I do that?

[image: The cube and the void rectangles]

The cube and the void rectangles

[image: The Geometry-Nodes structure]

The Geometry-Nodes structure

Thanks for your time and help

[Animation video](https://youtu.be/piRpAj_c8H8)
(Animation video)

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] below, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this node setup:

[image]

The scaling will be done by the index. I add 1 and multiply it with a certain value.

The start frame i realized by a new input variable for the input node and just subtract it from the frame.

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Only a doubt, why do you use the 'Store Named Attribute'?

Comment: uhm...r u kidding me? it was in your blend file...(just hidden behind another node) -  i wanted to make as less changes to your original to make it work....so i let your node in there.

Comment: oops! I thought you put it there for a reason and I was going crazy trying to undestand. Thanks again and sorry.